# Does a temporarily-enchanted item get a saving throw as a magic item if it is unattended?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, saving-throw

If someone casts, for example, greater magic weapon +3 on a bundle of arrows, are those arrows treated as magic arrows +3 for the purposes of receiving a saving throw, or are they still treated as non-magic items which would not be eligible for a save?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Breaking and Entering](http://dndsrd.net/carryingAndExploration.html#breaking-and-entering) on Saving Throws says, "Magic items always get saving throws. A magic item’s Fortitude, Reflex, and Will save bonuses are equal to 2 + one-half its caster level" (*Player's Handbook* 167), yet casting the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*greater magic weapon*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#greater-magic-weapon) [trans] (*PH* 251-2) does *not* transform the weapon or ammunition into magic items. Instead, the spell only grants the weapon or ammunition a magical enhancement bonus. The weapon or ammunition's saving throws would remain unchanged.

However, [Breaking and Entering](http://dndsrd.net/carryingAndExploration.html#breaking-and-entering) on Magic Armor, Shields, and Weapons also says, "Each +1 of enhancement bonus adds 2 to the hardness of armor, a weapon, or a shield and +10 to the item’s hit points" (*PH* 165), so the spell *greater magic weapon* does increase the weapon or ammunition's resilience.

Comment: So if you attacked a creature with vow of peace using said arrows, they would shatter without a save leaving the creator unharmed. But if someone tried to sunder your arrows somehow, they would be tougher than normal.

Comment: @WannabeWarlock RE: Vow of Peace. Tentatively, *yes*, but that's a pretty bold takeaway from this answer and kind of merits a separate question. I can imagine the DM ruling that arrows *when used as projectiles* aren't actually weapons and, instead, in the totally different *ammunition* category. It's not a particularly *fun* thing to imagine, but I can do it. Also, I didn't think there existed a group of players that'd allow a PC take the feat Vow of Peace. Or are you the DM and designing an antagonist for a party of evil PCs?

Comment: It's just the first example that came to mind of a save-or-die effect for objects. A better example is: arrows buffed such as that would still be vulnerable to shatter because they are still non-magical